# Theano profiling summary

Tags: python, profiling, theano

I am trying to learn how to profile in Theano. Below is some very basic code.

I set `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING` to 1 as advised. Also, I am not sure if it is necessary but I set `theano.config.profile=True` as well. This prints some output when the code completes running. But how do I capture / print / log this so I can actually analyse the results?

I can see from the web documentation that in the deprecated profiling approach with [profilemode](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/profilemode.html), there is a handy `profmode.print_summary()` function. Unfortunately the current profiling is not as well documented as the deprecated one.

How can I analyse the profiling results for these two functions?

```
theano.config.profile = True

# set this to 1 to allow profiling with GPU
# http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/profiling.html#tut-profiling
os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'

# Function 1 
x = T.dmatrix('x')
s = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-x))
logistic = theano.function([x], s, name='log_func')
print logistic([[0, 1], [-1, -2]])

# Function 2 
state = shared(0)
inc = T.iscalar('inc')
accumulator = function([inc], state, updates=[(state, state+inc)], name='accumulator')
print accumulator(1)
```

Comment: The output you see when the program exits is the equivalent output as from the old `profmode.print_summary()`. The simplest thing to do is to redirect the output into a text file so you can peruse it more easily. If you have a specific question about the output, please paste an example snippet from the output and ask the more specific question.